# Event is not updated with updated details in google calendar

Tags: node.js, npm, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm using npm module named as `ics` to create ics file and attach it in the mail.

> Refrence: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics

When first time email will be sent at that time ics file will be generated with below code snippet:

```
  const event: any = {
        start: [2022, 9, 2, 15, 0],
        duration: { hours: 0, minutes: 30 },
        title: `Appointment updated for service with cutter`,
        description: `Description`, // phone number
        location: `address`, // store address
        status: 'CONFIRMED',
        organizer: { name: 'Admin', email: 'admin@mailinator.com' },
        attendees: [
          { name: `jay`, email: `jay1@mailinator.com`, partstat: 'ACCEPTED', rsvp: true, role: 'REQ-PARTICIPANT' }
        ],
        uid: "efrtEW234deetijg45"
      }

      const { error, value }  = await ics.createEvent(event);
```

The above code works fine for the first time and ics file is attached to an email. But when I update the appointment time at that also I need to attach ics file in the email with updated details. And updated details would be below:

- Time, Title, Description, duration.

> I'm not changing uid parameter of event object at the time of update. It'll be same

> Issue is not related to generating ics file or sending an email.

Question:
When the email for the update event gets triggered at that time ics file will be attached to the email and when the user clicks on "add to calendar" button from the email then new event gets created in the calendar but ideally, the previous event should be replaced by a newer one.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Is the issue generating the ics or sending the email? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Thank you @LorenaGomez. I'll definitely keep things in my mind while writing a question. Currently, the issue is not generating ics file or sending an email.